# Unity Character Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh-collider

Have Mesh Colliders on everything except the Solider being a child of the Game Object renamed Player.

The Player has a Character Contoller surrounding the child or blue-colored soldier. In Game Play, he falls halfway through the road and gets stuck in Unity. Is there a fix for this????

I noticed the Unity forum had not answered a similar question about it since 2019.

Comment: The Unity forum is more or less abandoned ^^ sounds like you want to check your colliders ... either they are not big enough, placed badly or maybe some collisions between certain layers are ignored in the physics settings ... Hard to reproduce this based on the information we have here ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Colliders**

Make sure that the actual model / mesh of your character has a mesh collider applied to it and that the convex box is checked. Next make sure that your ground / whatever your character lands on has a collider attached to it whether this collider is of type mesh, box or really any collider it shouldn't matter but I'd recommend trying a cube with a box collider first. Also make sure that all of your mesh colliders actually have a mesh applied to them.

For your character controller double check that the size of it matches your characters model in both width and height. Apply the actual Character Controller to the Parent game object in your case named Player and apply the mesh collider to your actual character.

**Some Images of how it should look when correctly set up**

[How the parent "Player" should be set up simply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye6J3.png)

[How the actual character should be set up simply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkxUd.png)

[How your ground should be set up simply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWIqz.png)

Comment: Thank you for both the example pictures and the explanation

Comment: No problem. Did it work?